# How to set Azure-Native storage IdentityConfig in Pulumi

Tags: c#, azure-rm-template, azure-managed-identity, azure-storage-account, pulumi

I want to connect my storage account to a managed identity. I have created a managed identity, and follow the Pulumi documentation ([here](http://$%22/subscriptions/%7BbaseConfig.SubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BbaseConfig.ResourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/MyUserAssignedIdentity%22)). And it shows pretty clearly what the first parameter is supposed to be, the id of the managed identity. But what is the other input supposed to be?

I have tried the whole managed identity instance, object id, even the storage account id (although it would be strange if it needed it) and many others, but i can't figure out what is needed.

The code in question for the link is:

```
Identity = new AzureNative.Storage.Inputs.IdentityArgs
{
    Type = "UserAssigned",
    UserAssignedIdentities = 
    {
       { "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/res9101/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/{managed-identity-name}", },
     },
},
```

Comment: The link was broken, please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

The value should be `new Dictionary<string, object>()`:

```
Identity = new AzureNative.Storage.Inputs.IdentityArgs
{
    Type = "UserAssigned",
    UserAssignedIdentities =
    {
        { "/subscriptions/subid/resourcegroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/test", new Dictionary<string, object>() }
    }
}
```

If you need to calculate the ID dynamically, you should do something like this:

```
Identity = new AzureNative.Storage.Inputs.IdentityArgs
{
    Type = "UserAssigned",
    UserAssignedIdentities = userAssignedIdentity.Id.Apply(id =>
    {
        var im = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { id, new Dictionary<string, object>() }
        };
        return im;
    })
}
```

This is definitely not very user-friendly and hard to get right. An improvement is tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues/812).